# How to use multiple models in the view page with update?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working with 3 tables, Customer,Room and Reservation.
I want to create a reservation and passing the existing values of the room.

The table reservation contains columns (foreign key) roomid and customerid.

I know asp.net view works with only 1 model.

How can I pass 2 models in a view and a controller. Because I want to use the existing values of my room to add it into my new reservation.

This is the main scenario. I have a list of rooms, and when I press on Book a room, a new page will appear with details of the selected room. With this existing model I want to create a reservation page to assign reservation date and also create a new customer and his id add into my reservation table. I've tried viewbag,viewmodel and tuple but, when I make some changes, the debug still says null as an integer.

Comment: `I know asp.net view works with only 1 model.` Create a `SpecialModel` class, with properties for `Customer`, `Room` and `Reservation`. New up the `SpecialModel`, set the three properties, pass it to the view.

Comment: I'd suggest a new question. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts I've answered what I perceive to be your _primary_ question.

Answer (score 1):

Create a special ViewModel like below

```
public class ReservationViewModel
{
    public Room {get; set;}
    public Customer {get; set;}
    public Reservations {get; set;} 

}
```

then use it accordingly. the class implementation may vary according to your needs. This is sample

Comment: which means you couldn't map it.

Comment: you couldn't map your model to your input, that is why your model returns with null value.